# javascript: my IF statement doesn't work - trying to understand where i'm wrong

Tags: javascript

I wanted to compare an object attribute stored in a table (using `forEach`) and some text cached in my HTML file. If elements are identical the object is removed from Local Storage and from table list in DOM.

```javascript
console.log(inter.callbackTime, e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.innerText);
//return 20:30 20:30

if (inter.callbackTime === e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.innerText){
  console.log('yeah');
} else {
  console.log('looser');
}
//return looser
```

When I display items one by one, it's the same (string for both and equal value), but when I compare them in a conditional statement, it's wrong... What did I miss? I also tried forced type with:

```javascript
String(inter.callbackTime)
String(e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.innerText)
```

Anyway `if(inter.callbackTime == e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.innerText)` also doesn't work.

Console:
[image: console]

[mycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQz8U.png)

Comment: What does `.length` give for both? Maybe one has whitespace on it or hidden chars

Comment: Why don't you just debug it?

Comment: yes, you're right!
One return five and the other six. How could I miss that ...? I hate me ...

Comment: I am not very familiar with debug for the moment. I am learning by myself and there is so much things to know :)

Comment: Should be able to run `trim` on it in that case and then should work as expected.